# PostgreSQL and Strapi - password authentication failed for user "*"

Tags: postgresql, docker, strapi

I am trying to connect Strapi with PostgreSQL database. I am also using Docker in order to compose the "db". I have managed to make the PostgreSQL running on port **5432**, and I am also able to connect to the database with `docker exec -it nameOfContainer bash` command without any problems. The only problem I do have is that I can not connect to the database from Strapi. I keep getting error `password authentication failed for user "strapibase"`. I know that the username of superuser is "strapibase" but I keep getting errors on and can not run the Strapi `yarn run develop` command.

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:alpine
    networks:
      - strapi-app-network
    volumes:
      - db-data:/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: strapibase
      POSTGRES_USER: strapibase
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: strapibase

volumes:
  db-data:

networks:
  strapi-app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

#### database.js

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  defaultConnection: "default",
  connections: {
    default: {
      connector: "bookshelf",
      settings: {
        client: "postgres",
        host: env("DATABASE_HOST", "localhost"),
        port: env.int("DATABASE_PORT", 5432),
        database: env("DATABASE_NAME", "strapibase"),
        username: env("DATABASE_USERNAME", "strapibase"),
        password: env("DATABASE_PASSWORD", "strapibase"),
        schema: env("DATABASE_SCHEMA", "public"),
      },
      options: {},
    },
  },
});
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

#### docker ps -a

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                    NAMES
94873c9919bc   postgres:alpine   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   33 minutes ago   Up 26 minutes   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   strapi-backend-db-1
```

I do have pgAdmin4 also installed on desktop, tried adding server there also keep getting the same error

Comment: Look in the db server's log file

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Strapi and PostgreSQL. I have managed to get it working by changing the *connection* property from `username` to `user`.

Here is an example of how my **config/database.js** file looks like :

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  defaultConnection: "default",
  connection: {
    client: "postgres",
    connection: {
      host: env("DATABASE_HOST", "localhost"),
      port: env.int("DATABASE_PORT", 5432),
      database: env("DATABASE_NAME", "strapibase"),
      user: env("DATABASE_USERNAME", "strapibase"), // <--- here from username to user
      password: env("DATABASE_PASSWORD", "strapibase"),
      schema: env("DATABASE_SCHEMA", "public"),
      ssl: env("DATABASE_SSL", false),
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `db` (The name of database service name) as your `DATABASE_HOST` to connect successfully.

Comment: I tried changing it to "strapi-backend-db-1" still can not connect

Comment: @Samke11 Did you try just `db`?

Comment: I have and I get this error `error Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND db`

Comment: @Samke11 Are you using `strapi/strapi` docker image? or another image?

Comment: I am not. I cloned the repository from github, that my friend has been working on and now I am trying to connect to the database, and only `.yml` docker file that I have is this one for database

Answer (score 0):

Your `docker-compose.yml` only defines the database. It exposes port `5432` locally, meaning `localhost:5432` is the right hostname in this case.

Verify the connection locally by running `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U strapibase -d strapibase` and enter the password.